# How could I get the last inserted row from specific column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a table called users with columns(username , name , password , email) ,
I want to get the last inserted row in username column.

I tried something like that :

```
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT username FROM users ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1");   
$statement->execute();
$row = $statement->fetch();
```

But it's returning an array, I just need one value as a string.

How could that be done?

Comment: 1. Actually,You can use ```mysqli_insert_id``` or ```pdo.lastinsertid.php``` to get  the ID of the last inserted row or sequence value,and then you can use the id in you query sentence as a condition.
2. You can do as Jacky said.

Answer (score 0):

1. if you want to get the last inserted, you might want to use an increment int field as an ID, not a string.

selecting username and order it desc would not give you the last inserted username.

by using increment int id, you can do this

```
"select username from users order by id desc limit 1"
```

2. as for the username value of your code, you can do $username = $row["username"]